# Existe la consultas anidadas en mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lo que estoy intentando hacer en mongodb, es mostrar las respuestas a una publicacion, hay publicaciones con comentarios y cada comentario tiene sus respuestas, cada publicacion tiene su id "idPublicacion". cada comentario tiene su id "idComentario", y cada respuesta a un comentario tambien tiene su id

en el ejemplo, el id de la publicacion seria
`"idPublicacion": "000001"`,
el id de un comentario seria `"idComentario" : "111111",`

La cuestion es que quiero un json con todos los documentos que tengan `"idPublicacion": "000001"`, esto lo puedo hacer con un simple `find("idPublicacion": "000001")`, ahora por cada uno de ellos quiero, una lista con todos los documentos que apunten al id del comentario, o sea que me liste todas sus respuestas

Espero que se haya podido entender mi planteo, existe alguna sugerencia? Al menos algun dato para ir averiguando

Comment: hay varias soluciones, dependiendo como tengas los esquemas de datos. si estan todos en la misma coleccion (como documentos anidados) o son colecciones independientes. si puedes ponernos como los tienes, seria de gran ayuda para darte solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estas utilizando el ODM de moongose, te recomendaría esto si no entendí mal tu pregunta [Operador And](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta. Por favor leer [answer] y realizar el [tour]. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Saludos